# Error Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql

Hello can you help me with these error i get them idk how i just entered the site and i got this errors.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on boolean in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\settings.php on line 6

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['hash'])) { 
    $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `hash` = " . $db->quote(filter_var($_COOKIE['hash'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
    if ($sql->rowCount() != 0) { //line 6
        $row = $sql->fetch();
        $user = $row;
    }
}
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 42

```
        $hash = md5($steamid . time() . rand(1, 50)); 
        $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `steamid` = '" . $steamid . "'");
        $row = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //line 42
        if (count($row) == 0) {

            $name = str_replace("script", "*", $name);
            $name = str_replace("/", "*", $name);
            $name = str_replace("<", "*", $name);
            $name = str_replace(">", "*", $name);
            $name = str_replace("body", "*", $name);
            $name = str_replace("onload", "*", $name);
            $name = str_replace("alert", "*", $name);
            $name = str_replace(")", "*", $name);
            $name = str_replace("(", "*", $name);
            $name = str_replace("'", "*", $name);
```

Comment: md5 hashes are useless, they've been crackable for years. Use something stronger like a newer SHA algorithm. Also your code is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You're using PDO so make use of its parameterisation features.

Comment: Anyway chances are the reason you can't call these functions is probably because your query failed somehow.  http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php says the method will return `false` on failure, instead of returning a PDOStatement object. Turn on error reporting and see what's going wrong.

Answer (score -2):

There's absolutely NO reason to assume your query will always execute successfully. Your sin is to have no error handling, which means lack of checking what `query()` returned. And by docs it returns:

```
PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure.
```

so, as you get `boolean` it clearly means it fails on your query.